# Removing a menu item from Manager

Tags: php, content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution, extra

After I tested and removed MODX extra Ticket, there is still a non-working menu entry ticket_menu_desc in the Extras menu. How could I remove it? Somehow, Ticket's uninstallation script didn't remove everything needed. The error log is now flooded because Ticket files don't exists anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Menus** (top right menu `gear icon` -> `Menus`, path is `yourwebsite.com/manager/?a=system/action`), find your Ticket extra point in left menu tree, right-click on it and select "Delete Menu item".